# Screen recordings in JavaScript with navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia aren't seekable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob, web-mediarecorder, get-display-media

We are trying to Record the Screen in ReatJS with **navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia** API and downloading the video locally after converting the Stream into Blob.

To download the video I am converting the Stream into Blob and then used URL.createObjectURL() to get the url and created the  tag Programmatically and clicking it Programmatically to download the video locally.

I am able to download and play the video, but not able to seek the video with seek-bar in any video player.

When I checked the Properties of Downloaded video I could not see length. I think thats the problem but I am not sure how should I set the length while creating the blob.

```
   function startRecording(stream) {

  let options = {mimeType:'video/webm;codecs=vp8'};

  let recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream,options);

  
  let data = [];
 
  recorder.ondataavailable = event => data.push(event.data);
  recorder.start(1000);
  let stopped = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    recorder.onstop = resolve;
    recorder.onerror = event => reject(event.name);
  });
  return Promise.all([
    stopped
  ])
  .then(() => data);

}

export async function startCapture(displayMediaOptions) {
  let captureStream = null;

  try {
    captureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
  } catch(err) {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
  }
  console.log("captureStream >>",captureStream)
  if(captureStream ==null){
    console.log("recording cancel")
    return -1;
  }
  startRecording(captureStream).then (recordedChunks => {
    let recordedBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: "video/webm;codecs=vp8" });
    console.log(captureStream)
    const href =  URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);
    console.log(href);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = href;
    link.download = "RecordedVideo";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  })
  return captureStream;
}
```

Here is the Link of Video which was downloaded with above code:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rtniknYlhsYVX3oEV6V7SWoV3RsNupqK/view?usp=sharing

P.S. Please play the video after downloading it as it play well in brwser.

[image: Propeerties of downloaded video]

If you think I can record and download the video with other approach plese share the details

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FileReader` for the link.href.

Try this approach. This should work. (I didn't test it though).

```
startRecording(captureStream).then (recordedChunks => {
    let recordedBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: "video/webm;codecs=vp8" });
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(recordedBlob);
    reader.onload = e => {
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = e.target.result;
        link.download = "RecordedVideo.webm";
        link.click();   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Tried this code still getting the same result I still not able seek the video.

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to download and play the video, but not able to seek the video with seek-bar

The `MediaRecorder` API unfortunately [does not create seekable recording files](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-record/issues/119).

That's because it's a live recorder that generates data continuously and incrementally returns it to JS.

This makes it hard to produce a seekable WebM file, which would require mutating the start of the file with seekable cues after the fact.

The workaround is to remux the files afterwards, either using [ffmpeg](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-record/issues/119#issuecomment-285165579) or js libraries.